# Use GNU's tools instead of Busybox's for Alpine image

Tags: linux, gnu, alpine-linux, busybox

I use the golang:1.13-alpine image from Dockerhub, which contains lightweight Busybox's tools. I need to use GNU's version for some tools, e.g. diff.
So I'm adding a command to my Dockerfile to install it:

`RUN apk --no-cache add diffutils`

How can I call these GNU's tools (by file location?) in my code or set them as default?

I'm using `exec.Command()` function inside my Go code.

Comment: So did you try just calling them? They will be in PATH... `docker run -ti --rm alpine sh -c 'apk add diffutils && diff --version'` prints GNU diffutils  for me.....